# How to use hasRole in Spring Security properly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

hi what i trying to achieve is to protect a url that only one role can access to it, when i try add .hasRole("USER"), still the other role can access it. Here is how i do it :

here is my controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/couponapi")
public class CouponController {

    @Autowired
    CouponRepository couponRepository;

    @PostMapping("/coupons")
    public Coupon save(@RequestBody Coupon coupon) {
        return couponRepository.save(coupon);
    }

    @GetMapping("/coupons/{code}")
    public Coupon findByCode(@PathVariable("code") String code) {
        return couponRepository.findByCode(code);
    }

    @GetMapping("/something")
    public Coupon findByCodeX() {
        return couponRepository.findByCode("SUPERSALE");
    }

}
```

i want to protect `@GetMapping("/something")` only for ROLE_ADMIN, here is how my Spring Security Configuration looked like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailServiceImpl userDetailService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailService);
    }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/couponapi/coupons/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/couponapi/coupons/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/couponapi/something").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
}

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

here is my role class :

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(of = { "id" })
@Entity
public class Roles implements GrantedAuthority {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7314956574144971210L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Users> users;

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and here is my service that implements UserDetailsService class :

```
@Service
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users users = userRepository.findByEmail(s);


        if(users == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username Not Found");
        }

        return new User(users.getEmail(), users.getPassword(), users.getRoles());
    }
}
```

and here is my database role data :

[image]

as you can see i have ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN

and here is my joined database

[image]

** i just updated my question and i have answer of half of my issue, please read my answer below to see the latest issue

Comment: can you try changing `hasRole` to `hasAuthority`, doesn;t make any sense but if you can try

Comment: sure, i try this .hasAuthority("ROLE_USER") still the same result, not working

Comment: Ok, in `CouponController` please add a param `Authentication` and check what all fields are population inside that

Comment: did you mean like this?
    @GetMapping("/something")
    public Coupon findByCodeX(Authentication auth) {
        return couponRepository.findByCode("SUPERSALE");
    }

how do i check all fields population inside that?

Comment: Yes this way please

Comment: hi i just update my question and i add answer for half of my issue

Answer (score 2):

In spring security the most restrictive rules are defined first, therefore your configuration should look like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/**/something").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()               
            .and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
}
```

Comment: hi yes, i figure that one out, but i still have issue about HttpMethod.GET etc, i still can't get it work

Answer (score 0):

i find the culprit here, but not entirely i still missing the functional of HttpMethod one. here is how i fixed the role, in my Role class i do a mistake that i trying to implements the GrantedAuthority class, that the thing that cause this trouble (without HttpMethod issue). and here is how i fixed it

first, delete the impements and turn the role into usual @Entity class :

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(of = { "id" })
@Entity
public class Roles {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7314956574144971210L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Users> users;

}
```

then at class that implements UserDetailsService, add this code :

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

users.getRoles().forEach(d -> {
    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(d.getName()));
});
```

i cannot explain it in details, but i think List only need 1 string, that's string is a role name. then here is the full code :

```
@Service
public class UserDetailServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users users = userRepository.findByEmail(s);
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();

        users.getRoles().forEach(d -> {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(d.getName()));
        });

        if(users == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username Not Found");
        }

        return new User(users.getEmail(), users.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

if anyone can find out the fix for this line `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/**/something").hasRole("USER")` which is i want to use HttpMethod to differentiate each method with the same url, if someone have the answer, i will accept your answer. waiting for it

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your good presentation of your problem.

That’s what I underestood, you want to give access only to user with **Admin** role to this URL `/couponapi/something` and give access to this URL `/couponapi/coupons/**` for all authenticated users whatever their roles **(ADMIN or USER)**

Try use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole` and delete the first line `http.httpBasic()` ,  it worked for me.

So in the WebSecurityConfig.java file:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/couponapi/something").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

Then In the above section of code, you only give access to users with ADMIN authority to access this url `/couponapi/something` so user with USER authority can’t access it.

And since you have declared a password encoder bean, you can use it with the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring security 6.x i try changing hasRole to hasAuthority and its work!

Comment: the only info this adds to abenamor's answer is a version number